# batch counting findstr results for /f

Tags: batch-file

I have an apache.log file. Im trying to make a batch file to be able to count the total amount of logins. Basically a number of lines.
My initial idea was to set a variable results=0 and whenever findstr command gets a result i get +1 to variable value and in the end display the value. Dont know if thats the correct way of thinking.
so far i've got the impression **for /f** command will probably be the key, though i've never used it so many parts are unclear to me.
here is the example of .log file line

```
67.195.112.96 - - [22/Feb/2010:00:06:03 +0200] "GET /www/kurpiai/dalyviai/?did=118 HTTP/1.0" 200 41119 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Yahoo! Slurp/3.0; http://help.yahoo.com/help/us/ysearch/slurp)"
```

my attempt so far goes as follows:

```
findstr ^[1-9] apache.log  
for /f %%G in ('findstr ^[1-9] apache.log') do echo result %%G
```

now i understand that in this case **%%G** value gets replaced with each findstr result. and with this i get echo of every line that matches **findstr** and after that every ip adress. why?
i believe maybe somehow i could use the fact that **%%G** value changes every time to set my own variable. why does **%%G** get an ip value exactly?
or maybe im wrong and i dont need **for /f** for this task at all?

Comment: The reason you get only the IP address echoed for each matching line is that `for /f` splits lines into fields at the default delimiter, a blank. So `%%G` is assigned the first blank-delimited item ("word") which is the address. `%%H` holds the second "word" - a single hyphen here. Check `for /?` for more details on the `delims=` and `tokens=` parameters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd say you don't. Just combine your `findstr` command with the DOS style `wc -l`:

```
findstr "^[1-9]" abc.txt | find /v "" /c
```

The first part selects the lines which match your intentions, and the second part counts (/c) those lines not matching nothing (i.e., all).

**edit:**
If you need the result in a variable:

```
for /f %%a in ('findstr /R "^[1-9]" abc.txt ^| find /c /v ""') do set "count=%%a"
```

Comment: Why recommending `wc -l` (which seems to work) but then using `find` instead?

Comment: Because "wc" is a *nix command (Unix, Linux) and not included in Windows natively, "find" has been since DOS. Actually, "wc -l" and "find /c" do the same thing, namely count lines.

Comment: Oh, damn I forgot I have installed GNUtils for Windows :D